# Is it possible to prove that the encoding of existentials in System F is valid?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, higher-order-logic, constructive-mathematics

In Girard's [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/prot.pdf), under item 11.3.5, second-order existential quantification is encoded in System F using universal quantification as follows:

$$
\Sigma X.V \equiv \Pi Y. (\Pi X.(V \to Y)) \to Y
$$

Is it possible to prove this encoding is correct using natural deduction or sequent calculus? In other words, is it possible to prove the following in System F extended with existentials?

$$
(1)\quad \Sigma X.V \vdash \Pi Y. (\Pi X.(V \to Y)) \to Y
\\
(2)\quad \Pi Y. (\Pi X.(V \to Y)) \to Y \vdash \Sigma X.V
$$

I think I can prove (1), but not (2).

In case these propositions are invalid, how can we be sure the encoding is correct?

Thank you.

PS.

I understand intuitively why the encoding makes sense, but would like to understand the formal reasons.

This encoding is widespread, but I can't find a proof of its validity. In Haskell, for example, it is used to simulate existential types and in similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13654649) the explanation is informal. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/418701) self-answered question, which attempts to produce a proof, I think there are errors involving invalid variable capturing.

**Edit: Proof attempt of (2) based on Andrej's answer**

I.
$$
{
\Pi Y. (\Pi X.(VX \to Y)) \to Y
\over
(\Pi X.(VX \to (\Sigma Z. V Z))) \to (\Sigma Z. V Z)
} \, \Pi E 
$$

II.
$$
{
\hspace{8em}
\over
VT
} u
\\
{
\hspace{8em}
\over
\Sigma Z. VZ
} \Sigma I
\\
{
\hspace{10em}
\over
V T \to (\Sigma Z. VZ)
} \to I_u
\\
{
\hspace{10em}
\over
\Pi X. (V X \to (\Sigma Z. VZ))
} \Pi I_T
$$

III. From I and II:
$$
{
\quad
(\Pi X. (V X \to (\Sigma Z. V Z))) \to (\Sigma Z. V Z)
\qquad
\Pi X. (V X \to (\Sigma Z. V Z))
\quad
\over
\Sigma Z. VZ
} \to E
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *second-order logic* with *Natural Deduction*, you can see :

> - Dag Prawitz, Natural Deduction A Proof-Theoretical Study (1965)

or :

> - Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013).

Both prove :

> $ΣX.V \equiv ΠY.(ΠX.(V→Y))→Y$.

See van Dalen, page 150, **Theorem 5.5 (e)** :

> > $\vdash_2 ∃X^n \varphi ↔ ∀X^0(∀X^n((\varphi → X^0) → X^0)$.

*Proof*

$${ [∀X^n(\varphi→X)] \over (\varphi→X) } \, (\forall^2E)$$

$${ [\varphi] \quad (\varphi→X) \over X } \, (\rightarrow E)$$

$${ ∀X^n(\varphi→X)→X \over (\varphi→X) } \, (\rightarrow I) \, \text{(discharging the 1st assumption)}$$

$${ \exists X^n \varphi \quad ∀X^n(\varphi→X)→X \over ∀X^n(\varphi→X)→X } \, (\exists^2E) \, \text{(discharging the 2nd assumption)}$$

$${ ∀X^n(\varphi→X)→X \over \forall X(∀X^n(\varphi→X)→X) } \, (\forall^2I) $$

Thus :

> > $\vdash_2 ∃X^n \varphi \rightarrow ∀X^0(∀X^n(\varphi \rightarrow X^0) \rightarrow X^0)$.

---

For the other direction :

$${ [\varphi] \over \exists X^n \varphi } \, (\exists^2I)$$

$${ \varphi \rightarrow \exists X^n \varphi \over \forall X^n (\varphi \rightarrow \exists X^n \varphi) } \, (\forall^2I)$$

In parallel :

$${∀X^0(∀X^n(\varphi \rightarrow X^0) \rightarrow X^0) \over ∀X^n(\varphi \rightarrow \exists X^n \varphi ) \rightarrow \exists X^n \varphi } \, (\forall^2E)$$

$${ \forall X^n (\varphi \rightarrow \exists X^n \varphi) \quad ∀X^n(\varphi \rightarrow \exists X^n \varphi ) \rightarrow \exists X^n \varphi \over \exists X^n \varphi} \, (\rightarrow E)$$

Thus :

> > $\vdash_2 ∀X^0(∀X^n(\varphi \rightarrow X^0) \rightarrow X^0) \rightarrow ∃X^n \varphi$.

---

*Note*

For the rules, see page 147; in particular :

> $${\varphi^* \over \exists X^n \varphi } \, (\exists^2I)$$

and :

> $${\forall X^n \varphi \over \varphi^*} \, (\forall^2E)$$

where

> $\varphi^*$ is obtained from $\varphi$ by replacing each occurrence of $X^n(t_1,\ldots, t_n)$ by $σ(t_1,\ldots, t_n)$ for a certain formula $σ$, such that no free variables among the $t_i$ become bound after the substitution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do those books also show the proof for the other direction? It is the most troubling for me and I might buy one of them if they do (do you recommend one of them?).

Comment: I think now I understand how the other direction works with Andrej's proof using Coq. Thank you very much for your answers and references, I plan to read Prawitz's book!

Answer (score 2):

Coq seems to be happy with this. The easy direction (`sigT` is $\Sigma$ and `forall` is $\Pi$):

```
Parameter V : Type -> Type.

Lemma rabbit : 
  sigT V -> forall Y, (forall X , V X -> Y) -> Y.
Proof.
  firstorder.
Qed.

Print rabbit.
```

We get the following proof:

```
  fun (X : sigT V) (Y : Type) (P : (forall Z : Type, V Z -> Y)) =>
    sigT_rect (fun _ : sigT V => Y)
              (fun (x : Type) (p : V x) =>
                 (fun X1 : V x -> Y => (fun X2 : Y => X2) (X1 p)) (P x)) X.
```

where `sigT_rect` is the eliminator for $\Sigma$. But you asked about the converse:

```
Lemma fox : 
  (forall Y, (forall X , V X -> Y) -> Y) -> sigT V.
Proof.
  intro H.
  apply H.
  intros X Y.
  exists X.
  exact Y.
Qed.

Print fox.
```

The proof found is

```
  fun H : (forall Y : Type, (forall X : Type, V X -> Y) -> Y) =>
    H (sigT V) (fun (X : Type) (Y : V X) => existT V X Y)
```

This is quite simple, actually, here's a translation. Suppose
$$H : \Pi Y \,.\, (\Pi X \,.\,(V X \to Y)) \to Y$$
Then $G = H \,(\Sigma Z \,.\, V Z)$ has the type
$$(\Pi X \,.\, (V X \to (\Sigma Z \,.\, V Z))) \to (\Sigma Z \,.\, V Z)$$
and so we just have to apply $G$ to a function of type
$$\Pi X \,.\, (V X \to (\Sigma Z \,.\, V Z))$$
Such a function is
$$\lambda X \,.\, \lambda W \,.\, (X, W)$$
i.e., the dependent pairing function.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it now. The tricky part for me was eliminating the outer universal by applying it to `ΣZ. VZ`, which introduces the existential which remains after the final application. I have edited the question with an attempted proof using natural deduction, does it make sense to you?